# Syntax error when load csv file into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I got the path of the csv file by os and glob modules:

```
os.chdir('C:\myproject')
filename = glob.glob('*.csv')
new1 = str(filename[0]).strip("''") 
path1 =  'C:\myproject\\' + new1
```

And then use MySQLdb to load it to the database:

```
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE {0} INTO TABLE intens FIELDS \
TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES (ID, @timevar, intensity) set in_time = \
STR_TO_DATE(@timevar, '%m/%d/%Y %r'), record_ID =  \            
LAST_INSERT_ID()".format(path1,))
```

This code worked in MySQL when I pasted the path directly after INFILE command. However, I received following error messages:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 226, in execute self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:\\myproject\\aaa.csv INTO TABLE intens FIELDS TER' at line 1")
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing apostrophes around the file path

[UPDATED]

```
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE `{0}` INTO TABLE intens FIELDS TERMINATED BY `,` IGNORE 1 LINES (ID, @timevar, intensity) set in_time = STR_TO_DATE(@timevar, `%m/%d/%Y %r`), record_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()".format(glob.glob(r'c:\myproject\*.csv')[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I changed the code and it gave me another error: _mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (2, "File 'C:myprojectaaa.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)")

Comment: you are missing some slashes in your path. it should be `C:\myproject\aaa.csv`

Comment: i updated the answer to get the `csv` using `os` module

Comment: I would use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module to get CSV files from a directory rather than the conditional: `csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")` (this will get CSV files from the working directory, but you can specify a directory like: `glob.glob("../my_directory/*.csv")`

Comment: @sundance I changed to glob.glob as suggested. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I changed codes as your suggestion. I was able to get the full path by str(filename[0]).strip("''") . However, I still see the error: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax
; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
 syntax to use near 'C:\\myproject\\aaa.csv INTO
 TABLE intens FIELDS TER' at line 1")